# Whitesource Bolt fails to generate reports

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, whitesource-bolt

[image]

I have integrated Whitesource Bolt to Azure Pipelines but its failing to generate the reports.I have entered the activation codes and the process runs in the pipeline as well .Also the Whitesource Bolt tab is not showing up on my project sidebar. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $params = "$env:SONARQUBE_SCANNER_PARAMS" -replace '"sonar.branch.name":"[\w,/,-]*"\,?'
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SONARQUBE_SCANNER_PARAMS]$params"
```

The issue was the branch I was testing on was not the default branch of the repo. Therefore use the above task to override the branch name